# Simplifying an R function with many variables

Tags: r

I'm trying to implement this model below:

[image]

However my code for it is quite messy due to all the Zs and Us, I'm looking for some coding tips to make my code as short and simple as possible?

```
model = function(N,t1,t2){
  Z1 = rnorm(N,0,1)
  Z2 = rnorm(N,0,1)
  Z3 = rnorm(N,0,1)
  Z4 = rnorm(N,0,1)
  U1 = runif(N,0,1)
  U2 = runif(N,0,1)
  T = (U2+t2*U1)/(1+t2)
  X1 = (Z1+t1*U1)/(1+t1)
  X2= (Z2+t1*U1)/(1+t1)
  X3= (Z3+t1*U1)/(1+t1)
  X4= (Z4+t1*U1)/(1+t1)
  eps = rnorm(100,0,1)
  Y = 2*X1 + 3*T*X2 + X3*(T+1)^2+ 4*X4*sin(2*pi*T)/(2-2*sin(2*pi*T))+eps
  X = cbind(X1,X2,X3,X4)
  return(list(X = X, Y = Y))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the code below simplifies a bit

```
model = function(N,t1,t2){
  Z <- matrix(rnorm(4*N),nrow = N)
  U <- matrix(runif(2*N),nrow = N)
  W <- tcrossprod(U, rbind(c(t2, 1))) / (1+t2)
  X <- (Z + t1*U[,1])/(1+t1)
  eps <- rnorm(N)
  M <- cbind(2,3*W,(W+1)**2,4*sin(2*pi*W)/(2-sin(2*pi*W)))
  Y <- M*X + eps
  return(list(X = X, Y = Y))
}
```

Comment: Can the expression for `Y` be turned into a matrix product `X %*% M` for some `M`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yes, it is possible, but better to use `M*X` rather than `M%*%X` (`X %*% M` cannot meet dimension consistency). ` M %*% X` may need to construct a huge block matrix and reshape the product, which is not as easy as using `*`